# How to get attributes of individual elements in jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I am getting an array of element in jquery with this `$(".drawer-face")`

If I use `$(.drawer-face")[x]` I get the x element with `.drawer-face` returned to me.

I want to be able to check attributes within the x element but I get

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[6].attr is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:22` when I use `$(".drawer-face").[6].attr("title")` for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".drawer-face").eq(x).attr(...)
```

Use the `eq(#)` method to keep the element as a jQuery object.

```js
var $drawers = $('.drawer-face');

console.log( $drawers.eq(2).attr('title') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class='drawer-face' title="title 1">Title 1</a>
<a href="#" class='drawer-face' title="title 2">Title 2</a>
<a href="#" class='drawer-face' title="title 3">Title 3</a>
<a href="#" class='drawer-face' title="title 4">Title 4</a>
<a href="#" class='drawer-face' title="title 5">Title 5</a>
```

Comment: I'm getting `f.fn.init [button.drawer-face]` as the output from `$(".drawer-face").eq(6)`. If I go into that element I can see the fields but when I try to access them with `attr` I get undefined.

Comment: Please create a working example of this issue in your question.  @Blue

Comment: @Blue I've added an example to the answer to show that this approach does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$($(".drawer-face")[6]).attr("title")
```

`$(".drawer-face")[6]` gives html dom and jQuery `.attr()` won't work on that

---

You can use JS and jQuery together like

```
$(".drawer-face")[6].getAttribute("title");
```

Comment: I'm getting `f.fn.init [button.drawer-face]` as the output from `$($(".drawer-face")[6])`. If I go into that element I can see the fields but when I try to access them with `attr` I get undefined.